# Compare values of subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following SQL in a stored procedure which I need to update:

```
SELECT 
    MEM.Id,
    EN.artistName,
    EN.dateAdded,
    EN.voteStatus,
    ES.enterNextRound,
    ES.notified,
    ES.voted,
    GR.genre,
    ES.entrantId AS bandID,
    ES.rnd2Feedback AS feedback,
    ES.compositionVote,
    ES.vocalsVote,
    ES.originalityVote,
    (SELECT COUNT(Voted)
     FROM recEntrantStatus
     WHERE voted = 1
       AND roundId = 2
       AND entrantId = ES.entrantId) CountVoted,
    (SELECT COUNT(Voted)
     FROM recEntrantStatus
     WHERE roundId = 2
       AND entrantId = ES.entrantId) CountTotalVotes,
    (SELECT COUNT(Id)
     FROM recMembers) TotalJudges
FROM 
    recMembers AS MEM
LEFT JOIN 
    recEntrantStatus AS ES ON MEM.Id = ES.judgeId
LEFT JOIN 
    recEntrants AS EN ON ES.entrantId = EN.Id
LEFT JOIN 
    recGenre AS GR ON EN.genreId = GR.Id
WHERE 
    MEM.Id = @memberId
    AND ES.roundId = 2
ORDER BY 
    bandID DESC
```

This works in displaying all matching records, however I now need to just return the records where the value of `CountVoted` is less than `CountTotalVotes`.

I've tried add a simple comparison in the `WHERE` clause eg:

```
AND CountVoted < CountTotalVotes
```

I've also tried:

```
AND recEntrantStatus.CountVoted < recEntrantStatus.CountTotalVotes
```

and:

```
CountVoted.CountVoted < CountTotalVotes.CountTotalVotes
```

but this has the same outcome of the two fields being classed as either ambiguous or don't exist. So how do I should I adapt things to in order to be able to perform the comparison?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way would be to throw the whole query into a sub query:

```
SELECT     *
FROM       (
             --Your query here
           ) q
WHERE      CountVoted < CountTotalVotes
ORDER BY bandID DESC
```

**edit**

I changed the column names to what's in your query and what you mentioned in your description, rather what's in your attempted `where` condition.

**further edit**

You should replace your `ORDER BY` clause to the outer query as well..

**edit on the edit**

Just noticed you don't select the attribute you use in your `order by`, add to the selection, or choose a different attribute to order on

Comment: This throws the following error: SQL46047 :: The ORDER BY clause is not valid in views, inline functions, derived tables, sub-queries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML or OFFSET is also specified.

Comment: Ok, that at least updates, if I also remove the ORDER BY clause from the original (now sub) query. Ill check if it works and get back in a sec.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!